# Fixing incorrectly ISO-8859-1 decoded UTF-8 string in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have to deal with a library which is not in my control. It delivers a string which it decoded from a byte stream with ISO-8859-1. However the byte stream is UTF-8. So obviously the resulting string I get is wrong if it contains non ASCII characters.

So what I do to fix this is to convert the string back to the byte stream and decode it again with UTF-8. Like this:

```
byte[] raw = inputText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
String correctedText = new String(raw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I tested it with many examples and it seems to work. Is this always correct however or are there cases where this would not work? In other words: are there cases where decoding / reencoding any arbitrary byte array with ISO-8859-1 would not result in the original byte array?

Comment: the byte array F_raw, is ISO 8859_1?

Comment: No. "inputText" is the incorrectly decoded string. So decoding it back, raw is hopefully in UTF-8. It works in all the examples I have tried so far. But need to know if it always works.

Comment: Isn't the problem that something is feeding UTF-8 encoded text to a library that expects ISO 8859-1-encoded text?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is the root problem. But I can not change this side because I have neither control over the text which is fed into the library nor the library itself.

Comment: Okay, but be on the lookout for the sender(s) correcting their error by switching to ISO 8859-1. Then your unscrambling will actually be scrambling. A feature flag might help.

Comment: @Tom Indeed. We already did that. :-)

Comment: This will _probably_ never be a problem, but do mind the difference between ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252. These two are often confused, and they differ on some control characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ISO-8859-1` is a 1 byte per character encoding, it will always work. The `UTF-8` bytes are converted to incorrect characters, but luckily there's no information lost.

Changing the characters back to bytes using `ISO-8859-1` encoding gives you the original byte array, containing characters encoded in `UTF-8`, so you can then safely reinterpret it with the correct encoding.

The opposite of this is not (always¹) true, as `UTF-8` is a multibyte encoding. The encoding process may encounter invalid byte sequences and replace them with the replacement character `?`. At that point you've lost information and can't get the original bytes back anymore.

¹ If you stick to characters in the `0-127` range it will work, as they're encoded in `UTF-8` using a single byte.

Answer (score -6):

UTF-8 and ISO-88-1 encode ASCII charactesrs at the same way. Given this You should not have any losses only since your original input is ASCII.

Comment: Well we are obviously also dealing with non-ASCII characters. Otherwise I wouldn't have had a problem in the first place.